# Decomposition of second derivatives of an immersion

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Let be $M^n$ an $n$-dimensional smooth manifold and let $$X(\cdot, t): M^n \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}^{n+1}$$

be a one-parameter family of smooth hypersurface immersions in $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$. Xi-Phing Zhu states in his [book](https://books.google.ca/books/about/Lectures_on_Mean_Curvature_Flows.html?id=VnG5TzcyN4wC&redir_esc=y) on page 16 that
$$\frac{\partial^2 X}{\partial x^i \partial x^j} = \Gamma^k_{ij} \frac{\partial X}{\partial x^k} + h_{ij} \overrightarrow{n},$$
where $\overrightarrow{n}$ is an unit normal on $X(\cdot, t)$ and $h_{ij}(x,t) = \langle \overrightarrow{n}, \frac{\partial^2 X(x,t)}{\partial x^i \partial x^j} \rangle$, is valid by the Weingarten's equation, but I didn't understand how exactly the Weingarten's equation helps me to show that. Can anyone explain why this is valid?

Thanks in advance!

P.S.: The author assumes the Einstein summation convention in the book.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The tangential component of this vector equation is precisely the definition of the Christoffel symbols $\Gamma^k_{ij}$,  just as the normal component is the definition of the second fundamental form of the hypersurface.

Comment: $\nabla'_{\partial i} \nabla'_{\partial j} X = \left( \nabla_{\partial i} \partial j \right)(X) + h(\partial i, \partial j)(X) = \left( \nabla'_{\partial i} \nabla'_{\partial j} X \right)^T + \left( \nabla'_{\partial i} \nabla'_{\partial j} X \right)^{\perp}$ is this? Where I used the Weingarten's equation?

Comment: What are you calling the Weingarten equations? Usually the Weingarten equations refer to differentiating the unit normal vector and expressing the answer in terms of the second fundamental form $(h_{ij})$.

Comment: Let $M$ be a hypersurface in $N$ and let $n$ an unit normal field on a neighborhood of $p$ in $M$. If $Y$ is a vector tangent along $M$, then the Weingarten's equation is $\langle \nabla'_{X_p} n , Y_p \rangle = - \langle n , (\nabla'_{X_p} Y_p)^{\perp} \rangle$.

Comment: OK, and how do you define $(h_{ij})$?

Comment: $h_{ij}(x,t) = \langle \overrightarrow{n}, \frac{\partial^2 X(x,t)}{\partial x^i \partial x^j} \rangle$

Comment: In that case, the Weingarten equations are totally irrelevant.

Comment: I understood now, thanks! I was confused just because he said that the Weingarten's equation was necessary to obtain the relation, but I didn't see how.